# How to apply a git patch from one repository to another?

Tags: git, patch, git-submodules, git-patch

I have two repositories, one is the main repo for a library, and the other is a project using that library.

If I make a fix to the in the subservient project, I'd like an easy way to apply that patch back upstream.

The file's location is different in each repository.

- Main repo: ***`www.playdar.org/static/playdar.js`***
- Project: ***`playlick.com/lib/playdar.js`***

I tried using `git format-patch -- lib/playdar.js` on the playlick project, and then `git am` on the main playdar repo, but the differing file locations in the patch file raised an error.

Is there an easy way to apply the patch from a given commit on a given file to another arbitrary file elsewhere?

For bonus points, what if the file you want to apply the patch to isn't in a git repository?

Comment: similar: question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367254/how-can-i-modify-the-file-path-in-a-set-of-git-patches

Comment: Another similar question with helpful details about creating a patch and applying it to another repository (see also comments suggesting `git apply --stat ...` and `git apply --check ...`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/how-can-i-generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If manually editing the patch file is out of the question or infeasible, this can be done with standard options (available in `git apply`, `git format-patch` and GNU `patch`).

1. `-p<n>` removes `n` leading directories from the paths in the patch.
2. After processing `-p`, `--directory=<root>` prepends `root` to each of the paths in the patch before applying.

#### Example

So, for your example, to take a patch that was originally on `static/playdar.js` and apply it to `lib/playdar.js`, you would run:

```
$ cat patch_file | git am     \ 
          -p1                 \ # remove 1 leading directory ('static/')
         --directory='lib/'     # prepend 'lib/'
```

Comment: Any chance making this top answer? This is far easier than manually editing a patch file.

Comment: Sure, this is a better/easier answer, though @araqnid's answer is still good to know.

Comment: Relevant to adjusting the directory after first trying without `--directory`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121709/git-error-previous-rebase-directory-git-rebase-apply-still-exists-but-mbox-giv

Comment: From `man git-apply`: `-p<n>` Remove `<n>` leading path components (separated by slashes) from traditional diff paths. E.g., with `-p2`, a patch against `a/dir/file` will be applied directly to `file`. The default is 1.

In my case the source PR modified files in `web/packages` and I needed to apply the patch to a repo that only had `packages`, so I had to use `-p2`.

Answer (score 41):

The patch produced by `git format-patch` is simply a text file-- you can edit the diff headers so that it modifies a different path.

So for instance it would have produced something like this:

```
diff --git a/lib/playdar.js b/lib/playdar.js
index 1234567..89abcde
-- a/lib/playdar.js
++ b/lib/playdar.js
```

All you have to do is change `lib/playdar.js` to `static/playdar.js` and then run the patch through `git am"`

The patch should be readable by the standard GNU patch utility for people who don't have `git`--- but don't run `format-patch` with the `-M`, `-C` etc. options to produce rename patches in that case, because the support for them isn't universal.

Comment: Revisiting this page later… This is a better answer to the question asked than the previous "winner" that suggested submodules.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming both projects are git projects, it sounds like that [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) would be the perfect fit for you. This allows a git project dynamically link to another git project, essentially baking a git repo right inside another git repo, both having their own distinct lives.

In other words, add "main repo" as a submodule in "project". Whenever you commit/push new stuff in "main repo", you just `git pull` them back into "project".

Comment: Hmm, having read through the submodule docs, this doesn't sound like "an easy way" though it may well be the most robust.

It looks like I'd have to create a submodule containing just the `playdar.js` file then include that in both other projects (I don't want everything else from `www.playdar.org` in the `playlick.com` project)

I might just resort to manually editing the patch files for now to be honest. Or continue to copy paste between the two.

Cheers.

Comment: Here's a clear and thorough tutorial and getting started with git submodule for anyone else stumbling upon this question: http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html

Answer (score 4):

Using the `--relative` option to `format-patch` can improve the abstraction (hide irrelevant details about the repository from which the patch was generated).

```
[repository-with-changes]
git format-patch --relative=(path-to-library) (base-commit-for-patch) ## 'HEAD~1'
```

I have found the `--3way` option to be required when applying the patch (to avoid `does not exist in index` error) -- your mileage may vary.  Using `--directory=(...)` is likely only necessary if your target path is not the root of the repository.

```
[repository-to-update]
git am --3way --directory=(path-to-library) (patch-file)
```

---

- `format-patch` will create one patch file per commit to the current branch since 'base'.
- The documentation for the `--relative` option seems to be [missing in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16309053/86967), but it appears to work anyway (as of version 2.7.4).

Answer (score 2):

To complete [Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931882/how-to-apply-a-git-patch-from-one-repository-to-another/931895#931895), and to go for the bonus point

> what if the file you want to apply the patch to isn't in a git repository?

If you have access to the directories of the file candidate for a patch coming from a git repository, you could first transform that tree of directories/files into a git repository itself! ('`git init`': a git repository is just a .git within a root directory after all).
Then you would set that repo as a submodule for your main project.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new remote and pull from it. [Article with details.](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/04/30/diff-patch-and-different-git-repositories/)

```
$ cd <path-to-repoB>
$ git remote add repoA <git-URL-for-repoA>
$ git pull repoA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove (rename) temporarily the main repository.

```
cd to/main/project
mv .git .git_
cd to/sub/project
git apply patchname
cd -
mv .git_ .git
```