# How to apply a Git patch to a file with a different name and path?

Tags: git, filenames, patch, git-patch, git-am

I have two repositories. In one, I make changes to file `./hello.test`. I commit the changes and create a patch from that commit with `git format-patch -1 HEAD`. Now, I have a second repository that contains a file that has the same contents as hello.test but is placed in a different directory under a different name: `./blue/red/hi.test`. How do I go about applying the aforementioned patch to the `hi.test` file? I tried `git am --directory='blue/red' < patch_file` but that of course complains that the files are not named the same (which I thought Git didn't care about?). I know I could probably edit the diff to apply to that specific file but I'm looking for a command solution.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3367254/1959808

Comment: [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) is absolutely fantastic for stuff like that...

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You could create the patch using [`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) and then apply it using the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) utility, which allows you to specify the file you want to apply the diff to.

For example:

```
cd first-repo
git diff HEAD^ -- hello.test > ~/patch_file

cd ../second-repo
patch -p1 blue/red/hi.test ~/patch_file
```

Comment: Ah, nice, did not think of that. However, is there any way to do this with Git commands so that commit data (date&time, commit author, commit message) is kept the same?

Comment: It's possible that there's something you can do with `am` or `apply`, but I can't find it. If you find yourself duplicating changes a lot, there might be a better solution using submodules, or whatever your language of choice provides to share code (e.g. in Ruby you could extract the duplicate code as a gem).

Comment: This is actually documentation-related (source files are XMLs). Submodules are not really an option as I would have to make a strong case for them in our existing infrastructure.

Comment: On Windows, one can use `git-bash`, which is included in Git for Windows. `git-bash` includes several Unix commands, including `patch`.

Comment: Is the `-p1` flag to `patch` necessary? It seems to have worked for me without it.

Answer (score 95):

There is a simple solution that does not involve manual patch editing nor external script.

In the first repository (this may also export a range of commit, add the `-1` flag if you want to select only one commit) :

```
git format-patch --relative <committish> --stdout > ~/patch
```

In the second repository :

```
git am --directory blue/red/ ~/patch
```

Instead of using `--relative` in `git format-patch`, another solution is to use `-p<n>` option in `git am` to strip `n` directories from the path of the patches, as mentioned in a [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11263899/4475279).

It is also possible to run `git format-patch --relative <committish>` without the `--stdout`, and it will generate a set of `.patch` files. These files can then be fed directly to `git am` with `git am --directory blue/red/ path/to/*.patch`.

Comment: This still relies on the fact that the file names are the same, right?

Comment: Should be noted that the `--directory` option appears to require you to specify the full path of the directory relative to the repo root; something like `--directory=./` while chdir'd into a subdirectory in the repo won't work.

Comment: Using `--3way` helps with `does not exist in index`: `git am --3way --directory (relative-path) (patch)`

Comment: Use `-k` key in both commands to don't strip the first line of the commit message.

Comment: Using `--3way` not only helps with "does not exist in index" errors (as pointed out by @nobar), but also allows you to cleanly handle merge conflicts. Instead of leaving conflicted files untouched, a conflict block is added that can then be resolved.

Comment: is there a way to to run `git am --directory ./ *.patch` so that the paths in the patch are applierd to the current directory ?

Comment: Good answer. Do not forget the `-p<n>` if you need to strip parent folders, and `--reject` if you encounter "patch does not apply" (it will apply the hunks it can and leave you the rest for manual application).

Comment: didn't work in Windows. But worked like a charm in WSL.   LINUX RULEZZZ

Comment: Note that if both directories are cloned on the same machine, you can pipe the output of one command to the other one: 
`git -C /path/to/first/repo/sub/dir format-patch --relative -1 --stdout <committish> | git am --directory other/dir -3`

Answer (score 9):

Building upon the answer by @georgebrock, here's a solution I used:

First, create the patch files as usual (eg. `git format-patch commitA..commitB`).

Then make sure that your target repository is clean (there should be no changed or untracked files) and apply the patches like this:

```
cd second-repo
git am ~/00*.patch
```

For every patch file you will get an error like "error: XYZ does not exist in index". You can now apply this patch file manually:

```
patch --directory blue/red < ~/0001-*.patch
git add -a
git am --continue
```

You have to do these three steps for each patch file.

This will preserve the original commit message etc. without requiring any special `git format-patch` command or editing the patch files.

Comment: Good answer, I think this is the best foundation for any kind of "non-standard" patch manipulation. I do it in 3 steps. **(1) Commit to text** - `git format-patch -1 commitA --stdout > thing.diff` ; **(2) Edit the patch file** until it will do what I need; **(3) Text to commit** `git am --3way thing.diff` which has the advantage that you can accept the parts of the patch that apply cleanly, and use `git`'s standard conflict resolution process for the parts that don't.

Comment: With current git versions, the current diff can be shown with `git am --show-current-patch=diff`, so the patch step can be changed to `git am --show-current-patch=diff | patch --directory blue/red`. This saves you from remembering which patch file to specify in each commit.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the two files are exactly the same in your situation, thus the patch is likely to succeed.

However, **in case you want to apply a patch to a similar, but not exactly the same file, or you want to do an interactive patching, you will use three way merge.**

Say you modified File `A`, let's denote `A~1` as the previous version, and you want to apply the diff between `A~1` to `A` to File `B`.

Open a three way merge tool, for instance Beyond Compare, the path of left panel is `A`, middle panel is the common ancestor so the path is `A~1`, the path of right panel is `B`. Then, the lower panel shows the result of applying the diff between `A~1` to `A` to File `B`.

The following figure illustrates the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FYI:  I recently had problems trying to download a patch from Github and applying it to a local file (which was an "override" in a new location).

`git am` wouldn't apply the patch either because the file was "not in index" or "dirty."  But, I found that the simple `patch` command *could* apply the patch.  It did prompt me for the name of the file to be patched.

Got the job done, anyway ...