# TortoiseGIT different file merge

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Problem Statement:
What is the way to merge changes from a revision from file A (10_3**4**_0_0.XML) to file B (10_3**5**_0_0.XML) in `TortoiseGIT` in 2 different branches?

Background of the problem: We recently did a SVN to GIT migration, the later realized that the team is heavily using the `TortoiseSVN` file merge functionality WITH selecting changes from a revision.

We were not able to find similar functionality in `TortoiseGIT`. This is not the same as GIT Cherry Picking. In Cherry picking you can select commit/set of commits to merge from the same file in 2 different branches.

Example: `TortoiseSVN` Process.

**Step 1: Select File and click merge.**
[image]

**Step 2: Select merge option**
[image]

**Step 3: Select the file and the branch you want to merge from**
[image]

**Step 4: Select the revision that you want the changes from**
[image]
[image]

**Step 5: Continue to merge**
[image]

**Step 6: Merge results**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526321/how-to-apply-a-git-patch-to-a-file-with-a-different-name-and-path), one way to do this from the command line is :

- create a patch file describing the diff on the first file (using `git diff`)
- apply it on the second file, using the standard `patch` utility

In more details :

```
git diff revisionA^ revision -- 10_34_0_0.XML > patch_file
cat patch_file | patch 10_35_0_0.XML

# you can write the above as a one liner with no tmp file :
git diff revisionA^ revision -- 10_34_0_0.XML | patch 10_35_0_0.XML
```

On Windows, you can run this from `git-bash` (the installation comes with the `patch` utility).

---

I wouldn't know how to do this through `TortoiseGIT`'s GUI however.

Comment: This was very helpful, below is the exact command that was used. We were able to create the patch using the TortoiseGIT GUI, then applied it using git bash.


**patch --binary 10_35_0_0.XML patch_file.patch**