# How can I contribute a patch to github?

Tags: github

I don't want to fork a project, but I would like to submit patches for inclusion; should I do this on the issue queue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You *should* [fork the project](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-forks/). In Github, this is very cheap. This way, you can push your changes how you want to *your* repository, and then [make a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) to have them included in the official repository.

You can then delete your fork after that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t fork a project, that means:

- you clone the original repo directly;
- you cannot push directly back to it (because you are not declared as a contributor).

Then you can indeed use the issue queue to [reference a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit).
If said patch isn’t too big, you can directly copy/paste its textual form.
If not, you can copy it to some [pastebin site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) and link it from your issue ticket.