# When applying a patch is there any way to resolve conflicts?

Tags: git, git-am, git-apply

I am on windows.

For various reasons we have multiple git instances of different svn branches.

Many times I want to fix an issue in repository A, generate a patch, and apply it to repository B. This works fine except if there are conflicts.

When rebasing I just right click the folder and use tortioseGit and select the resolve option. This brings up a nice gui to let me work through my conflicts.

Is there any way to accomplish this with rejected patch chunks?

Here is my current approach to creating/applying the patches

```
git format-patch master --stdout > c:\\patch\\file.patch
git apply --reject --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace c:\\patch\\file.patch
```

Comment: I usually do it by hand when all patching options fail...

Comment: If the merge fails, it is because the program _can't_ figure out how to un-ambiguously do the merge.  You should get a file with <<<<, ===, >>>> sets and you have to go in and resolve them by hand.

Comment: Yeah doing it by hand is a real pita when your talking a few 100 rej hunks.

Comment: That's when you'd want to use `git mergetool` and do a 3-way merge with the gui of your choice (i'm partial to kdiff on windows)...

Answer (score 360, accepted):

To generate your patch do the following:

```
git format-patch --stdout first_commit^..last_commit > changes.patch
```

Now when you are ready to apply the patches:

```
git am -3 < changes.patch
```

the `-3` will do a three-way merge if there are conflicts. At this point you can do a `git mergetool` if you want to go to a gui or just manually merge the files using vim (the standard `<<<<<<`, `||||||`, `>>>>>>` conflict resolution).

Comment: I didn't know about the `...` notation; it's documented in the [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) man page.

Comment: There certainly are  alot of ways to get the commits you want and nothing else... That being said, what I was trying to convey is not what I actually said... Now it is fixed to really mean what I wanted... (or so I think...)...

Comment: It may be useful to add `--ignore-whitespace --ignore-space-change` to `git am` too. I had trivial merges that did not go through without it.

Comment: `git apply -3 changes.patch` seems to work for me as well

Comment: git -am -3 works for me.  After git am -3 , I have to stage all the changes with git add patch. git am --continue. Then the patch will be applied successfully.

Comment: Even though the patch doesn't apply cleanly I still get "No files need merging" from `git mergetool`. Instead I had to find the base commit the original patch used, apply on top of that (luckily my repo had this) and then rebase.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @jozxyqk. Neither `git am -3` nor `git apply -3` will actually drop conflict markers into my files, even though I get messages like `Applied patch to 'configure.ac' with conflicts.` and `error: patch failed: ...`. This is on `git 2.17.1`. Perhaps when some files can't be patched at all, git rolls back?

Comment: I got the same issue as @nh2, did you ever find the problem?

Comment: I wonder if this really works according the original question, when those commits (index SHAs in patch) are alien to the current repo?   (No good test at hand, but `-3` won't work with patches processed e.g. with `interdiff` or other advanced means. It requires to first establish the starting file state (e.g. committing a copy) of at least the conflicting files somewhere in the current repo at a suitable parent (with good similarity), and from there do `apply + rebase / cherry-pick`)

Comment: What about Mercurial users? :(

Comment: @payne this is a git question...? no idea about mercurial unfortunately

Answer (score 16):

If you are frequently running into the same conflict set when applying patches, rebasing or merging then you can use git rerere (reuse recorded resolution) function. This allows you to pre-define how conflicts should be resolved based on how you resolved them in the past. See http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html for details of how this works.

Answer (score 15):

Just use

```
git apply -3 <patch_name>
```

it will allow you to fix conflicts

Comment: Not always...
```error: repository lacks the necessary blob to perform 3-way merge.```

Answer (score 5):

TortoiseGit has a merge feature that can open patch files.

There's a picture of it [here](https://tortoisegit.org/about/screenshots/#TortoiseGitMerge).

Comment: Actually the merge option might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Really? I've not used tortoise in a long time, but the linked page has the text "TortoiseMerge can open Git patch file directly, you review it and patch to working copy.", so it seems like it should!

Comment: it does open patch files... however, sometimes the patch file format breaks tortoisegitmerge.  i've never been successful with diff -u, but rather diff -c output.

Comment: You can also right drag patches on a working tree folder and select "Apply patch serial" (for patches like 0001-xxx.patch, ... 0002-xxy.patch) or "Apply single patch file".

Answer (score 4):

My approach is:

- Create an "Integration"-Branch where the files are identical
- Apply the patch to this Integration-Branch
- Merge or rebase it to master (don't know if rebase is useful here, because I don't know what will happen when applying further patches)