# Unwanted stuff written in file when cherry-picked

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-am

Recently I got to know about `cherry-pick` command in `git`, and it turns out to be a useful command. I learnt from the resources on how to use it to cherry-pick contents from other's repo. After I used the command, the contents got cherry-picked from other's repo branch, but alongwith them I also had few lines in different parts of the file,

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD

>>>>>>> 53de559...
>>>>>>> 0fa87af
```

(Such types of unwanted stuff were present wherever changes were made). I just want to know whether these lines would affect the file or are simply required by the `git`. If they are not required how do I remove them.

I followed steps that were described [here](http://voidcanvas.com/cherry-pick-format-patch/)

Comment: these are conflicts, did you see any messages while running `git am`?

Comment: The guide misses this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589612/2303202

Comment: here's how activate diff3 style markers with `git am`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16968982/2303202

Comment: Yep, these are merge conflicts markers.  Yes, they will most likely absolutely affect the application if these are in source code files.  Probably the source would not even compile.

Comment: Do I have to remove them by myself, or are there any commands?

Comment: These should've been removed when you got the conflicts to begin with. Can you check the commit you cherry-picked, does it contain these markes in the original file, or were they introduced by the cherry-pick? If the latter, did you not get a message stating a merge conflict?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, they were introduced by the cherry-pick. I manually removed them. Thanks