# how to easily select a single commit when a range must be specified?

Tags: git, patch, revision-history

Given a repository like this:

`A--B--C--D--E--HEAD`

I want to use `git format-patch` to export only commit `C`. What would be an easy way to specify this commit?

From what I can tell, `git format-patch <sha1 of B> <sha1 of C>` would work, but that's pretty cumbersome (juggling with two hashes). Isn't there an easier way to specify this, something like "give me all commits immediately following B"?

I use Git 1.7.1 and would prefer solutions for this version; but if newer versions have substantial improvements in this area, this might be interesting as well.

Comment: Good find! While I don't understand _why_ it works :-/ , `git format-patch -1 <sha of C>` as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658352/2148773 appears to work for my case. Can someone mark my question as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to work with `C` and "`parent of C`":

```
git format-patch C~ C
```