# Pull Request, ignore some file changes

Tags: git, github, pull-request

When I do a Pull Request on GitHub (against master branch), can we ignore some file changes, like

- we have one file named 'fileA' in branch 'release', and we have the same file in 'master', but we do some changes in 'fileA' in branch 'release'
- when we do a Pull Request, is there any way we can ignore the changes in 'fileA', do not let that merge into 'master'.

Comment: No. Create branch without modifications of fileA

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't ignore some files from a pull request selectively.
Two workarounds for this can be -

First -

- Create a new branch from 'release'
- Replace the non-required files from 'master'
- Create pull request from this new branch

Second -

- Create a new branch from 'master'
- Put changes of required files from 'release'
- Create pull request from this new branch

Any of this method will work. Which will be easier depends upon how many files are to be included / excluded.

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703636/12138397, it is not possible to exclude files in a Pull-Request, and the alternatives which have been proposed also work.

But there is a simpler solution to it. Here I am considering **staging** as my target and **dev** as my source

```sh
root
|-- src
|   -- app.py
|-- .gitignore
|-- settings.py
|-- requirements.txt
```

Let's say, I would want to ignore the **settings.py** file from being merged

- First move to the **target branch** *(the branch to which you want to merge the 
  changes)*

  ```sh
  git checkout staging
  ```
- Then you can use the ***git checkout*** command to selective pick the files you want to 
  merge

  ```sh
  git checkout dev src/
  ```
- This will only merge the files changed inside ***src/*** folder

  > NOTE: You can also do it selectively for each file.
- Then push to remote repository

  ```sh
  git push origin staging
  ```

But this solution is useful only if the files to be excluded is small.

Answer (score 2):

Create branch with last commit you agree with:

```
git branch my-branch <sha>
git checkout my-branch
```

Select commits you want to pull request [as patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit):

```
git format-patch -10 <sha> --stdout > 0001-last-10-commits.patch
```

Apply patches:

```
git am < 0001-last-10-commits.patch
```

Your commits will be as they was. You can `git push -u origin my-branch` immediately.

Answer (score 1):

My scenario was: I am using CI/CD in AWS and the pipeline reads from `buildspec.yml`. In the dev pipeline I need a specific Cloudfront id written in `buildspec.yml` and in the main pipeline the Cloudfront id changes. My steps to prevent changing this file in a Github PR were:

1. Backup the content of the files in another external file
2. Delete the `buildspec.yml` file
3. Add the `buildspec.yml` file in the `.gitignore` file
4. Push these changes
5. Create a new `buildspec.yml` from the Github UI directly. Set the values corresponding from each branch (dev and main)

This way the `.gitignore` ignores the different versions of `buildspec.yml` in dev and main. In every PR, I get the changes of all files but the `buildspec.yml` does not appear. It is worth mentioning that if I make a change in the `buildspec.yml` file, git will recognize that change and make it commitable (I am not sure why).

I hope this helps anyone :)