# Github ignore downstream configuration files in pull-requests

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

We have two repositories: Upstream and Downsteram, with a single `config.lua` file that can be different between them. We want to use Pull Requests from Downstream to Upstream (and vice-versa), while ignoring the `config.lua` file.

Relevant SO answers that aren't usable:

We don't want to spend time excluding the `config.lua` file each time, so the answer in [Github - Pull Request, ignore some file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703140/github-pull-request-ignore-some-file-changes) doesn't work for us.

This answer ([Using git, how do I ignore a file in one branch but have it committed in another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another/39280410#39280410)) doesn't work anymore apparently (and this is the same `master` branch anyway).

I couldn't get Github to work with the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014154/7656871 . 
I've tried the following:

1. created the config.lua file and changed it differently so as to
   cause a conflict (which seems like a hack, but apparently needed!)
2. added .gitattributes with content `config.lua merge=ours`
3. added .gitconfig with content:

   `[merge "ours"]
   driver = true`
4. the github PR still detects the change and claims it cannot automatically merge.

I also think it's a bad hack to have to create a merge conflict so this merge strategy would fire (see [Is it possible to exclude specific commits when doing a git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332528/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specific-commits-when-doing-a-git-merge/3970442#comment28185122_3970442)). It will make the process complicated if there are multiple Downstream forks.

Is there no simple way to ignore one Downstream configuration file when doing pull requests?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, GitHub is just a pretty frontend for Git repos. So this is a Git question since a GitHub PR is really about merging two branches - there's no way of excluding files there.

---

The solution for this problems is usually to not commit config files at all but rather commit a `foo.cfg.example` while adding `foo.cfg` on gitignore.

If you cannot avoid commiting config files, why not give them unique names - e.g. `foo-team1.cfg`, `foo-team2.cfg`, etc? That way they are tracked but you won't have conflicts or problems with other people's config changes overwriting yours.