# Exclude files from the new pull request (github)

Tags: github

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/blog/exclude-files-from-the-new-pull-request-experience) has a feature to exclude files from the new pull request and I'm wondering if there is a similar feature in **GitHub**?

**Scenario:**

- I have a Branch A that has changes in `.travis.yml` I pushed those
- changes and create a PR  I need to merge all changes in this branch
- except the changes in `.travis.yml` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull Request, ignore some file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703140/pull-request-ignore-some-file-changes)

Comment: @DaemonPainter No it does not as I'm looking for a plug-and-play solution not a work around

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature in GitHub (to the best of my knowledge confirmed by a quick google search).

The best alternative, excluding the proposed duplicate question for using a workaround, is to refer to [this blog page](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-07-31-removing-files-from-a-pull-request/), stating that:

> Previously, if you wanted to use GitHub to remove files from a pull
>   request, you’d need to switch to the pull request branch and look for
>   the individual file to delete it. Now, if you have write permission,
>   you can click on the ‘trash’ icon for a file right in the pull
>   request’s “Files changed” view to make a commit and remove it.

I haven't tested this method, but I feel like it is somehow related to the rejected "[alternative workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703140/pull-request-ignore-some-file-changes)".

Comment: If u delete the file, and merge the PR to master then this file has been deleted from master too

Comment: Don't blame me if GitHub doesn't provide the functionality you need. I believe it is made pretty clear at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: There is no blam, it is just not the answer and I really appreciate your help.