# Github Actions - Different workflow file per branch

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I have a project in Github, which has 2 branches - dev & master.
Each branch has a different workflow yml file.
On pull request from dev to master it also includes the dev's yml file in the changes.
How can i make the .github/workflows ignored on pr's? Is it even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull Request, ignore some file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703140/pull-request-ignore-some-file-changes)

Comment: Not exactly, since I want to know this for workflows specifically. Maybe it isn't recommended, and there is a certain standard which I don't know.

Comment: Workflow files are not given special treatment. This means that even for these it is not possible to automatically exclude them from a PR. You must either always create a second Dev-branch and change the workflow file there or make a branch from Master and drag all changes from Dev onto it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I'm kind of new to github, and still haven't fully mastered workflows. For now I've created a reusable workflow on my main branch, and all branches use it and "inject" different secrets and inputs to it. My question is - what is the recommended way to do this? When you have multiple branch who require similar workflow just with different variables?