# Why can't another programm see my local (unpushed) commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-extensions

I have made a commit in VS2015, but I haven't pushed it yet. Then I made a fetch with Git Extension and I can see, that I'm 2 commits behind the remote branch. But Git Extension doesn't show me my local commit. When I search after the commit hash in Git Extension, he also doesn't find it. Why?

`git status` also only shows me that I'm two commits behind the remote branch.
`git log @{u}..` shows nothing on console.
`git log origin/master..HEAD` only shows commits from the old fetched remote.

I wanted to do a rebase, but now I don't know if thats a good idea, if Git Extension can't see my local commit.

Comment: Who is "he" in this scenario?

Comment: "he" = Git Extension

Comment: I'm sorry for this question, but are you sure you work on the same folder? Do you use one branch?

Comment: @Ivan: It's the same folder and the same branch. I opened GIT Extension from VS and here the current settings are taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `git reflog` to see a history changes in your local repository.

If you can't find your commit there - check that you don't have two copies of the repository in different places.

Comment: No, it was the same copy. But you were very helpful! If you are interested in the solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`git reflog` shows me:

```
1d63279 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 9af729af1fbb639a5616528a31e7773f99f564d3 to refactor
9af729a HEAD@{1}: commit: My missing commit
1d63279 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 0e302fee7cbb0ba1306a75e024e324291e3e361f to 1d6327972bd9ac1a585d947e634b69f891a78325
0e302fe HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from refactor to 0e302fee7cbb0ba1306a75e024e324291e3e361f
1d63279 HEAD@{4}: commit: My old commit
```

So it seems that I had checked out a special commit in the meantime and worked on that. My solution to this was to make a [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658352/426227).

```
// create patch
git format-patch -1 9af729af1fbb639a5616528a31e7773f99f564d3
// show stats
git apply --stat 0001-My-Commit-Message.patch
// check for error before applying
git apply --check 0001-My-Commit-Message.patch
// three-way merge and apply the patch
git am -3 < 0001-My-Commit-Message.patch
```

Now everything should be OK and I can work further. But I don't know what happens with the old commit.