# Make patch or git diff of Github issue commits?

Tags: git, github, repository, patch

In the following Github issue are there 35 commits

- https://github.com/sharelatex/web-sharelatex/pull/103/commits
- https://github.com/sharelatex/web-sharelatex/pull/103/files

**Question**

How can I get a copy of those commits as patches or git diff's, so I can keep a local copy of these?

From what I can tell, not all commits have been accepted, but I like to have a copy of them all anyway.

This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit), as the commits in that answer have all been committed.

Comment: @kowsky The question is about GIthub pull requests, not local repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually do this by adding the word `.patch` or `'.diff` onto the end of the url, i.e.:

https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/sharelatex/web-sharelatex/pull/103.diff

However it appears that (I think) because the original repository isn't present, this doesn't work.

This also precludes manually cloning the original repo and then creating a patch from there on the command-line.

However you can get access to the branch containing a PR by doing the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/sharelatex/web-sharelatex
cd web-sharelatex
# edit .git/config - change the 'origin' fetch entry to:
  fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
git fetch -a
git checkout remotes/origin/pr/103
```

You can now get access to all the commits in that PR and generate patches etc.