# How can I compare two commits in git and move the changed files to a new directory?

Tags: git

I am trying to generate a patch with only the files that are changed.

If the last 4 commits are A --> B --> C --> D, I want the latest version of the changed files only from all 4 commits.

So if File123.txt was changed in commit A and again in commit C, I want the version from commit C to be moved to a new directory, along with all the other changed files from all 4 commits.

Comment: Is the goal to create a patch that contains all the changes from all four commits? We could suggest a command that will directly generate the patch, no need to move files around.

Comment: e.g. `git diff HEAD~4..`

Comment: I need to run a script on the files that are changed, so pulling them into a directory is the easiest way to do that for me. I ran git diff HEAD.. but I don't see any kind of output.

Comment: @user1601376. That's because you're doing it wrong most likely

Answer (score 1):

> I ran `git diff HEAD..` but I don't see any kind of output.

That is expected, since `git diff HEAD..` would compare two commits, the second being... HEAD itself.

```
git diff @
```

That would compare HEAD with its parent commit (unless HEAD is a merge commit, in which case, you need the `-m` option (By default, `git diff-tree --stdin` does not show differences for merge commits).

I would also consider the [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172120/6309)) to generate the patches (to apply with [git am](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a single *patch* file, which combines the changes of the last four commits, just run :

```
git diff xx D   # where 'xx' is the parent of A
# equivalent to :
git diff A^ D

# or if D is your active commit (HEAD) :
git diff HEAD~5 HEAD
```

If you want to *list the files* that were modified in these commits, just add `--name-only` to any of the commands above :

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~5 HEAD
```