# whether can github repository merge files from one repository to another one

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have two github repositories to manage the same project at first.
Then I make some changes in one repository files.
How can I do to make the changes to another repository?

The two repositories are independent of each other，not the master and branch relationship

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution (for GitHub repo or any two repos), would be to isolate your changes in a patch, and apply  to your second local clone of your second GitHub repo.

See as an example:

- "[How to apply a git patch from one repository to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931882/how-to-apply-a-git-patch-from-one-repository-to-another)".
- "[git: Apply changes introduced by commit in one repo to another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816292/6309)"