# How can I generate/apply git patches only for commits that alter specific files

Tags: git, git-diff, git-patch

I have two git repos that are forks of each other and I need to occasionally import commits from one to the other.

For example:

`git-repo1` has this directory structure:

`repo1/project1/src`

`repo1/project2/src`

while `git-repo2` has the following directory structure:

`repo2/src/`

What I'd like to do is take a series of commits and generate patches only for commits that altered files within a particular subdirectory (say `repo1/project1/src`) and ignore all commits that only alter files anywhere else.

Or alternatively, generate patches for all the commits, but only apply the patch IF it alters files within a particular directory.

I need to preserve the metadata about the commits so playing with `git diff` doesn't seem like a viable option.

The directory structure between the forked git repos differs.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

**UPDATE1**

I see this question ([How to apply a git patch from one repository to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931882/how-to-apply-a-git-patch-from-one-repository-to-another/11263899#11263899)) in terms of coping with differing directory structures.

But what if the patch speaks of modifying files that simply do not exist? I would like to ignore such changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `git rev-list --reverse`*`series`*`-- repo1/project1/src/ \`
>   `| xargs -I@ git format-patch --stdout @^! >mystuff.patch`

will spit the commits in *series* that affect that subdirectory into `mystuff.patch`

Then,

```
cat >mystuff.sed <<\EOD
/^(From [0-9a-f]{40}|diff --git )/!{H;$!d}
x
/^From /b
${h;s,.*--,--,;x}
\,^diff[^\n]* [ab]/repo1/project1/src/,!{$!d;x;b}
${p;x}
EOD
```

and

```
sed -Ef mystuff.sed mystuff.patch >justmystuff.patch
```

will strip out all the hunks outside that directory.  You can apply with

```
git am justmystuff.patch
```

with `-p`*`n`* and `--directory=new/path/to` as desired.

(edit: EOD --> \EOD so the cat above doesn't try to substitute)

Comment: When using the command "sed -rf mystuff.sed mystuff.patch >justmystuff.patch"

Im getting the error "sed: illegal option -- r" 
Have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Use `-E` instead, `-r` is now an historical spelling.  Fixed in the answer, thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you can give an explanation on your sed script !

Comment: Search and replace with your favourite text editor also works (well, worked for me at least). I just changed the paths and removed the bits that referred to files outside the subdirectory. I didn't touch the commit hashes - and I don't know if the automagical script above does as I'm like @Neil.

Comment: Is it possible to make changes that allows you to also keep creations and changes in other particular files or multiple paths? For example if I have a sub-directory `sub-repo-a/` and externally to that I have a file called `.sub-repo-a.settings`. I would like to keep commits that affects ither of these paths.

Comment: How to teach the `mystuff.sed` magic to add to the patch commit message something like `imported from hash`?

Maybe one will need to add `-k` to both `git am` and `git format-patch` to include possible [blah] in the commit messages. Also adding `--no-renames` seems to make `git am` happy if a file was moved from `repo1/project2/src` to `repo1/project1/src`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7767933/komar, a cool guy on the sed irc channel, suggested: ```# Collect patch header and body of chunks in hold buffer
/^(From [0-9a-f]{40}|diff --git )/!{
  # detect end of header and insert line "llvm-monorepo: HASH" from "From HASH"
  /^---$/{
    x
    s/(From )([0-9a-f]{40})(.*)/\1\2\3\n\nllvm-monorepo: \2/
    x
  }
  H;$!d
}
x

# ouput "From" line from header
/^From /b

# if patch in '[ab]/lvm/' - output it
\,^diff[^\n]* [ab]/llvm/,!{$!d;x;b}

# other chunks will be skipped```

Fixes the case if there is a diff pasted in a commit log

Answer (score 1):

if the two repositories have common history (they are both forked from the same repository, but have evolved differently), you could use [cherry-picking](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) to import commits selectively from one branch to another.

create a local repository with two remotes (your two diverging repositories)

find the commits in repositoryA that touch certain files

```
 $ git checkout repoA/master
 $ git log sub/dir/ectory
 a34256f ...
```

cherry-pick those commits into the branch of repositoryB

```
 git checkout repoB/master
 git cherry-pick a34256f
```

Comment: No, unfortunately they do not share a history. :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried few different methods found in here and other answers but didn't find a solution fitting for me. This is what I found out.

You can give `git format-patch` a path as an argument so that it'll create patch only for only those paths.

```sh
git format-patch HEAD --root $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD) --stdout -- repo1/project1/src/ > git.patch
```

The command `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` is used to fetch the initial commit ref from the repository

Applying the patch can be done with

```sh
git am git.patch
```

In my case I also wanted to skip one directory level when applying the patch because I was moving one whole directory from a repository to a separate repository. `git apply` which gets used by `git am` has a flag `-p<n>` which removes  leading path components from the diff paths. The default is 1, so `git am -p2 git.patch` did the work for me.