# How do I use --relative with git format-patch?

Tags: git, version-control

When I use `git diff --relative HEAD^..HEAD`, I get some nice output for a patch that I strip out the path outside the directory it is in.

I am starting to use `git format-patch` and I would like to also use `--relative` but don't see any options for that. How would I get the same effect?

Thanks

Comment: `--relative` is missing in the (newer?) docs.  Maybe it is deprecated.  It is documented for this version: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch/1.6.0

Comment: It isn't in the format-patch docs per say, it is in the git diff docs. So try `git help diff` and you will see --relative in their.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git help format-patch` shows

> ```
>    git format-patch [-k] [(-o|--output-directory) <dir> | --stdout]
>    ...
>                       **[<common diff options>]**
> ```

So, just `git format-patch --relative`.

Comment: Thanks! I had just searched the page for relative didn't see anything. You just taught me something even bigger than this one thing. I am now wondering how many man pages have similar descriptions in their arguments list!!

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---relativeltpathgt is one such man page section..