# How do I merge multiple patches with git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-patch

I have several patches that I need to merge into my branch

The guide line for this was:

```
git checkout 4.4
git checkout -b 4.4-xamarin
git am Engine/Plugins/XamarinUE4/Patches/*
```

In `Patches` are 33 different patches, the problem that I have is that `git am Engine/Plugins/XamarinUE4/Patches/*` doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I get the following output:

```
D:\Ue4src\UnrealEngine>git am Engine/Plugins/XamarinUE4/Patches/*
Stray d:/Ue4src/UnrealEngine/.git/rebase-apply directory found.
Use "git am --abort" to remove it.
```

If I look at "Date modified" it seems no file has changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't have a `git rebase` underway. If not, you could safely delete the `rebase-apply` directory: [Git error: previous rebase directory .git/rebase-apply still exists but mbox given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24121709/520162)

After that, applying the patches with `git am` should be fine.