# How to fix a Git am error ".git/rebase-apply still exists but mbox given"?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, git-am

I have a folder which contains `.patch` files only. When I run a command

```
for myPatch in /d/FolderWithPatches/*.patch; do git am "$myPatch"; done
```

I receive a `fatal: previous rebase directory .git/rebase-apply still exists but mbox given.` error. I tried both using `git am --abort` and simply deleting the `rebase-apply` folder - neither of this helped actually. Can you help me to fix my issue?

EDIT: I know the issue on [Git error: previous rebase directory .git/rebase-apply still exists but mbox given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121709/git-error-previous-rebase-directory-git-rebase-apply-still-exists-but-mbox-giv). The answers provided there don't help me to deal with the problem.

Comment: @phd Obviously I looked at the link you provided before I posted the question, I've searched all the Internet before it.

Comment: Did the `rebase-apply` directory actually go away? The `/d/` suggests maybe you're on Windows, and sometimes Windows won't remove things.