# Can I access Git LFS files globally from other repositories in my organisation?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Any information I've found so far lead to a 'NO'.

But it is possible to store LFS files in a custom location, so technically its possible to access them, but  If a change was made to LFS files from a different repo, the change wouldn't be historically represented in the original repo.

The question is, is there a way to globally access the LFS files uploaded to the regular LFS store in Bitbucket from another repo in my organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get what the goal is here. if you want to get the lfs object from one repo to the other, this object need to be tracked as an LFS object in both repos, by which it means, you might want install git lfs in both repos. I didn't find other solutions other than doing this though.

For example, there're two repos `A` & `B` sharing a lfs tracked object `obj`. `A` updates `obj` and you'd like to access the latest `obj` from `B`? it's impossible unless:

in `A`, after you update `obj` with a commit checked in:

you also need to update the commit in `B`. you can achieve this by creating a `git patch` in `A` and apply it in `B` with reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931882/how-to-apply-a-git-patch-from-one-repository-to-another).

Comment: Yes tho be clear, this was the goal in the original question.